# Does repairing a helicopter inflight gain you points?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

In a game this morning on Caspian Border I was an engineer passenger in a helicopter.

I spent 5+ minutes going round in the back constantly using the repair tool to bring the health back up to 100%. At times we were taking lots of fire so I was repairing from 25% on several occasions.

Should I be getting XP points for this?

While I helped keep the helicopter up in the air for a significant period of time it didn't seem to contribute much to my individual score.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't getting points? Normally you get 10 points ever few seconds while repairing a vehicle that has someone inside it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I wasn't. Then again, I'm also new to the game so I'll pay closer attention next time. Where should I be looking to see the points?

Comment: Can you repair a heli while it is flying only if you are in one of the non-gunner seats?

Comment: I was able to use the repair tool when riding in the back and not in the gunner seat.

Comment: @FishOfPrey The points should show up where you'd normally see points for kills (like the 100 etc). If it doesn't, I'm guessing it's a bug due to you being inside the heli, and you should probably report it.

Comment: This is a bug and will probably be fixed in a future update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was doing this too and it didn't give me points. As of now, repairing a vehicle while inside it doesn't trigger the game to give you points. Ideally you should get points but since it could easily be abused due to the helicopter being repaired constantly when under heavy fire. This is probably for the best to stop players from boosting up their XP while a passenger inside a helicopter.

Comment: This seems to line up with what I've been reading on the battlelog forums. While you can repair in flight you don't get points for it.
[Battlelog: Repairing A Helicopter While In Flight](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654347710015268/)

Comment: Strange as when doing this in battlefield bc2 this was possible. but from a more realistic point of view it doesnt make sense

Comment: The XP gain is most likely blocked to prevent infinite leveling (as long as you have a good pilot). Maybe DICE forgot to add some lines of code that would allow an XP gain from repairing from inside the copter. Only the programmers know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As at the 12th of December 2011 I found I was able to get squad repair points when repairing a little bird in flight.

I spawned into a helicopter piloted by a team mate and got the repair points. This is almost certainly related to the [Dec 1st PS3 update](http://blogs.battlefield.ea.com/battlefield_bad_company/archive/2011/12/01/battlefield-3-ps3-update-imminent.aspx) but I can't see any clear reference to it in the release notes.

Unless the pilot needs to be in your squad for it to give you points?

Answer (score 0):

I'm often repairing scout helicopters in flight and get lots of points for it, at least on the PS3. What's more, it also gives me scout helicopter XP.