# Are you awarded points for reparing vehicles?

Tags: battlefield-3

I repaired a couple of vehicles the other day (I typically equip mines) and didn't get any points for it. I have no repairs listed on my BattleLog either, but I recall the vehicle being fixed.

Comment: How big were the repairs? I remember in Battlefield 2142 that you had to repair about 1/3rd of a vehicle's health to get a repair point. Not sure what it is in Battlefield 3, but that might be your problem.

Comment: Hrm, it was pretty dinged up and needed the repair. I'd say it was flashing that serious warning, where it blows up if you don't fix it. I can't remember off the top of my head, though. I'd think it'd work like healing or ammo that you get 10, 10, 10 until it's fully fixed. Have you ever tried repairing and been given points for it or never tried? I just want to know if you get points at all, not when/how much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Battlefield Wikia has this to say on the subject of [repair](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Support_action#Repair):

> Using a wrench or repair tool to fix a vehicle, device, or strategic object belonging to the team.
>
> For vehicles, another teammate must be occupying the vehicle in order to earn repair points. It is common courtesy for a player to enter a vehicle being repaired solely to allow the engineer to earn repair points, and to give back control when the repairs are done.

I also see several threads that say if you're in the vehicle when repairing it (especially aerial vehicles) you won't get credit, including a question on this very site:

[Does repairing a helicopter inflight gain you points?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33578/does-repairing-a-helicopter-inflight-gain-you-points)

I don't believe that you need to repair any particular percentage of the damage done to a vehicle, there is/was a glitch in the game about repairing EOD bots that are being damaged by teammates, and you can see in the [video on this page](http://kotaku.com/5856959/how-to-get-crazy-battlefield-3-points-shits-broke), this guy's getting tons of repair points for relatively minor repairs.

Doing a repair gives you +20 points, and a Squad repair counts for +30.

Comment: Ah, see I think I jumped out of the vehicle and repaired my own. That makes sense then so people can't abuse it. Thanks, @agent86.